# Subgroups of semisimple Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a connected semisimple Lie group.

1. If $N$ is a normal closed semisimple Lie subgroup of $G$ and $\Lambda$ is a closed discrete subgroup of $G$. Is $N\Lambda$ a closed subgroup of $G$?
2. If $H$ is a closed connected semisimple Lie subgroup of $G$. Is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$ semisimple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No to both.

1: try with a choice of direct product $G=N\times H$...

2: take $G=\mathrm{SL}_4$ and take $H=\mathrm{SL}_2\times\mathrm{SL}_2$ embedded as group of block-diagonal matrices each of determinant 1. What is the normalizer then?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in the first part of the answer if $\Lambda$ is a discrete subgroup of $H$, then isn't $N\times \Lambda$  semisimple?

Comment: My first part is just a hint. Take $G=N\times H$ for some semisimple $H$, and find $\Lambda$ which makes a counterexample (i.e., discrete but whose projection on $H$ is not closed).

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get that yet. Can you explain more please why we don't want it closed and if you have a good example. Thanks again!

Comment: Find a cyclic discrete subgroup in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})\times \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ whose projection to the second factor is not closed.